Mass update table and column descriptions in google big query
I need to update table and column description for more than 150 tables in BigQuery. Is there a way to write a procedure which can loop through each table and alter the table and update desc for columns that are missing description on the table.
I tried to loop through each table and each table has like more than 100 columns. As a result every time I am issuing hundreds of alters. Is there any way to solve this?

The following will work:
FOR row IN (
  select "street" as col, "street address" as description
  union all
  select "city" as col, "city" as description
  union all
  select "postal_code" as col, "postal code" as description
)
DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  ALTER TABLE <table_tef>
  ALTER COLUMN %s
  SET OPTIONS (
    description='%s'
  );
  """, row.col, row.description);
END FOR;

just adjust <table_ref> and preferably replace my nested sql query with single table reference (I kept it explicit - so it's crystal clear what goes in).
Then for multiple tables, using the same method:
FOR row IN (
  select col, description, table_to_update from <table_desc_ref>
)
DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  ALTER TABLE %s
  ALTER COLUMN %s
  SET OPTIONS (
    description='%s'
  );
  """, row.table_to_update, row.col, row.description);
END FOR;

where <table_desc_ref> should be a table containing columns, along with their refined descriptions and relevant table reference.

Hi thank you for your response. If i use a for loop , it will generate alter for each and every column in a table . For example if a table has 100 columns it will generate 100 alters . I need to be able to loop for every column in a table example.
Alter table table_name alter column column_name1,alter column column_name2. I need the table name once and alter all the column desc in the table and then goto the second table and so on. In this way for a single table only one alter will be issued in the backend.how can i solve this?

you cannot do what you are after in the backend, only front end really i.e. loop. Also even if big query would permit ALTER COLUMN for multiple columns (which to best of my knowledge no SQL platform does) - what makes you think that it would be faster than loop. Remember that columns traditionally had upstream objects on them (indexes, triggers), hence most of changes was recursive in nature. I get that BQ is not RDBMS, but at the same time it takes a lot from RDBMS-s logically. Don't think about SQL like you do about programming language - it's its own beast...
